# Run Tasks In Parallel While Maintaining Option To Cancel Them And Do Something When Everything Finishes

Tags: .net, windows-8, async-await, c#-5.0

I call an async method which in turn calls needs to start several async opertions.

Once all the async operations are finished, I need need notify the caller whether the operations were completed or canceled. The code can be seen below. It seemingly works until it crashes with an FatalExecutionEngineError. I do not make any P/invoke or unsafe calls.

```
   public class Fetcher
    {
        private List<ItemsBoundToUI> uiItems;
        public async Task<bool> Fetch()
        {
            List<Task> currentlyRunningTasks = new List<Task>();


                var src = new CancellationTokenSource();


                foreach (var channel in this.uiItems)
                {
                    var task = FetchForItem(channel, src.Token);
                    currentlyRunningTasks.Add(task);
                }

            bool wasCancelled = await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(currentlyRunningTasks.ToArray(),
                                                                    (s) =>
                                                                    {
                                                                        bool wasC = s.Any(ss => ss.IsCanceled);

                                                                        return wasC;
                                                                    }
                                                                    );


           return !wasCancelled;
        }

        private async Task FetchForItem(ItemsBoundToUI channel, CancellationToken src)
        {
            var subitems = await dataRepository.GetSubItemsAsync(channel.ID);

            if (src.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;
            channel.SubItems = subitems;
        }
    }
```

The error message says

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x6c108144, on thread 0xd94. The error code is 0xc0000005. This
>   error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

How is it possible to wait until all the tasks have finished, or until they are cancelled and then return a value indicating whether they finished or were cancelled?

Comment: Not an answer to what you're seeing, but if you want to return whether it was cancelled, why not just return src.IsCancellationRequested?  FWIW, calling the CancellationToken 'src' in the FetchForItem method seems odd :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FatalExecutionEngineError` sounds like a CLR bug. Please develop a minimal repro and report it to Microsoft via [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

It's best to let cancellation work the way it was designed (via exceptions). To `await` multiple tasks, use `Task.WhenAll`.

```
public class Fetcher
{
  private List<ItemsBoundToUI> uiItems;
  public async Task<bool> Fetch()
  {
    List<Task> currentlyRunningTasks = new List<Task>();
    var src = new CancellationTokenSource();
    foreach (var channel in this.uiItems)
    {
      var task = FetchForItem(channel, src.Token);
      currentlyRunningTasks.Add(task);
    }

    try
    {
      await Task.WhenAll(currentlyRunningTasks);
      return true;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private async Task FetchForItem(ItemsBoundToUI channel, CancellationToken src)
  {
    var subitems = await dataRepository.GetSubItemsAsync(channel.ID);
    src.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    channel.SubItems = subitems;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem exists without the cancellation. I'm in dire need of a work around.

Comment: If you're in dire need of a workaround for a Beta platform, the best option would be to contact Microsoft. Don't forget your MSDN subscription includes some support tickets.

Comment: P.S. `0xC0000005` is an access violation. This error isn't possible with verified managed code; it can only be a result of incorrect p/Invoke, unsafe code, or unmanaged code. Do you have *any* p/Invoke, unsafe, or unmanaged code in your solution at all?

Comment: Nope, none. However, I searched the MSDN forums and it appears this might be a CLR bug. Hopefully it will be fixed in the RC.